# Find a block of negative numbers in a file, change the sign (from negative to positive), and add a constant? Awk

Tags: awk

My data files look like the example below.  There are gradual changes in the value of numbers going down the entire column, with occasional abrupt switches (from one row to the next) to blocks of negative numbers, then abrupt switches back to positive numbers.

I need to find every block where there's an abrupt switch to negative numbers, then remove the negative sign, then add a constant (like 3).

"Abrupt switch" means going from 23.x on one row to -23.x on the next row, plus or minus 2 integer values (i.e., we could go from 23.x to -25.x on the next row).  "Gradual" means a much smaller change, like 8.x to 9.x or (if we go from positive to negative) from 1.x to -2.x.  I only want to remove the negative sign from the blocks of numbers where there has been a major abrupt swing to negative values (23.x on one row to -23.x).

```
8.78012707
9.56501824
10.44979594
11.39474484
12.36147845
13.31673905
14.23514676
15.10013966
16.64348846
17.32466111
18.53815563
19.08329762
20.53520542
20.97620979
21.40371647
21.82209161
22.23668008
23.5165991      
-23.80172389  # This is where a switch happens. I want to remove the negative sign on this row and the following few rows that are negative and also add a constant to each value.
-21.54423258
-20.72179371
-20.80158154
-22.49201142
-22.91858912
-23.3271475
-23.70612457   # This is where the problem block ends.
23.72263622
23.43048236
23.19582689
23.02839487
22.93637418
```

I have been told that Awk would be the way to go but my skills are not up to the job.  From other people's questions, I made this but keep getting a syntax error and can't figure out a solution.  Can anyone see the problem?

The other issue is that I want to change the sign only if the number on the row above the first negative number in a block is within a value of "1" of the negative number once its sign is removed.  Is it even possible to do that?

```
awk '{print ($1<0)? $1=$1*-1 + 3}' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

---

In reply to anubhava, this is what I would want for the problem block (the block in the data above that is between the two comments).

```
    26.80172389  # This is where a switch happens. I want to remove the negative sign on this row and the following few rows that are negative and also add a constant to each value.
    24.54423258
    23.72179371
    23.80158154
    25.49201142
    25.91858912
    25.3271475
    26.70612457   # This is where the problem block ends.
```

Comment: @anubhava, I will add it to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: what if I have a range of positive numbers - `34,35,36,5000,50001,23000` - those look like fairly `abrupt` changes to me soooo, what do we do with these?  you need to be more specific with the defintions of `abrupt` and `gradual` ... something that can actually be programmed (eg, I'm not aware of any programming languages that support `something like 23 ... followed by -23 (or thereabouts)` 'logic') :-)  or does this even matter? will you **ever** want to maintain **any** negative numbers, ie, are you really asking us to remove **all** negative numbers?

Comment: @markp-fuso, thanks for the feedback.  My definition is fuzzy.  If a positive number on one row is similar to a negative number on the next row when we ignore the negative sign, then that is what I mean when I say that that would be an "abrupt" switch.  23 and then -23 or -22 or -21 on the next row.  "Gradual" (not something I want to change) would be a number on one row differing by up to three or four integer values from a number on the next row (positive or negative).  Is that clearer?  The problem numbers I want to change do represent swings from positive to negative.

Comment: @anubhava, yes.  I would like to remove the negative sign and add a constant.  I chose "3' here.  If I'm not being clear I can explain another way.  Thanks.

Comment: But adding constant `3` in `-23.70612457` should make it `26.70612457` right?

Comment: @anubhava, yes it should.  I need glasses.  Sorry.  I edited it.

Comment: Please clean up your question to contain all relevant information and give specific values you'd like us to use to get the output you provide from the input you provide., Replace all the `like 3`s, `something like 23`, `-23 (or thereabouts)`, `like 2`s etc. with specific values.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for the feedback.  I will try to make it clearer.  I do want to communicate that there is some fuzziness because the values I want to change represent major swings from positive to negative.  I want to change those and not touch the other smaller changes and don't want to confuse people by making them think the change criteria are very rigid.  I will think about how to communicate this, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Somewhere between your initial fuzzy requirements and code someone has to decide what those values are (or the algorithm to calculate those values) so yeah, unfortunately you need to do that in your question so we can help you write the code to implement them.

Comment: @EdMorton, I changed an "and" to "then" as in, remove the negative sign, then add three.  I hope that clarifies things.  About your other comment, yes you're right.  I do need to make the criteria rigid.

Comment: Apparently you are trying to fix **Accidental Sign Changes** (ASC for short) in your data. What's missing is an accurate definition of ASC. Let `A` be one of your values and let `B` be the next one in your data file. Let us try to formally define an ASC between `A` and `B`. From what you wrote we can deduce that it could be: `(A>=0) and (B<0) and (|A+B|<T)`, where `|X|` is the absolute value of `X`, and `T` is a threshold value. Do you confirm? If yes, what is the value of `T`? If not, please fix the formula **in your question**, using a **similar formalism**.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, thank you.  I am trying to fix simulation results.  The simulations take place in a box that has periodic boundary conditions.  When something crosses a boundary, it comes in at the other side and that can lead to a negative sign in the result.  I can identify that that has happened when a positive number suddenly switches to a negative number (a less dramatic change of the results over time is a normal calculation result).  I need to find all places in my results where there's a sudden switch to negative values and correct them and am currently checking the solutions get all.

Comment: @user3292696 Fine. So, do you confirm? If yes, what is the value of `T`? If not, please fix the formula **in your question**, using a **similar formalism**. You probably understand that if you do not have yourself a clear definition of what you try to achieve, there is very little chance that we can help you, do you? And, by the way, wouldn't it be much better to fix your bogus simulation environment instead of trying to detect and fix the erroneous results it produces?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, thank you but I'm clear and the people who have answered so far also seem to be.  I am currently busy with their suggestions.  My simulation environment cannot be fixed.  The issue is intrinsic to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v n=3 '!ab && int($1) == -1 * p {ab = 1} $1 >= 0 {ab = 0} ab {$1 = sprintf("%.8f", (-1 * $1) + n)} {p = int($1)} 1' file

8.78012707
9.56501824
10.44979594
11.39474484
12.36147845
13.31673905
14.23514676
15.10013966
16.64348846
17.32466111
18.53815563
19.08329762
20.53520542
20.97620979
21.40371647
21.82209161
22.23668008
23.5165991
26.80172389
24.54423258
23.72179371
23.80158154
25.49201142
25.91858912
26.32714750
26.70612457
23.72263622
23.43048236
23.19582689
23.02839487
22.93637418
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -v n=3 '
!ab && int($1) == -1 * p {ab = 1}
$1 >= 0 {ab = 0}
ab {$1 = sprintf("%.8f", (-1 * $1) + n)}
{p = int($1)}
1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Staying away from trying to translate OP's 'fuzzy' logic; assuming the logic in OP's `awk` attempt is correct.

The `awk` ternary operator has the form:

```
test ? if-true : if-false
```

OP's `awk` attempt has an incomplete ternary operation (missing the `: if-false` clause) and hence a reason receiving a syntax error.

Updating OP's `awk` to print `$1` (as the `: if-false` clause), and provide support for a variable as the constant to add:

```
awk -v x=3 '{print ($1<0) ? $1*-1 + x : $1}' infile.txt
```

This generates:

```
... snip ...
22.23668008
23.5165991
26.8017                 # start modified output
24.5442
23.7218
23.8016
25.492
25.9186
26.3271
26.7061                 # end modified output
23.72263622
23.43048236
... snip ...
```

If OP wants the same scale on the outputs we can use `printf` to generate the desired format:

```
 awk -v x=3 '{printf "%.8f\n", ($1<0) ? $1*-1 + x : $1}' infile.txt
```

This generates:

```
... snip ...
22.23668008
23.51659910
26.80172389             # start modified output
24.54423258
23.72179371
23.80158154
25.49201142
25.91858912
26.32714750
26.70612457             # end modified output
23.72263622
23.43048236
... snip ...
```

Comment: thank you for this.  It's obviously my fault because I came up with the suggestion (and thank you for working with it), but for some reason, the results are a little unpredictable.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @user3292696 what do you mean by `unpredictable`? all I had to do was fix the syntax in your code ... this answer (ie, your code) flips the negative sign and adds 3 ... same results as you posted in your question ... same results as generated by anubhava ... and your code is actually a bit less complicated than the other answer